# How to forbid apt to remove certain package during dist-upgrade?

Tags: debian, apt

Is any way to forbid apt (apt-get) do remove specific package during dist-upgrade, but permit it upgrade/downgrade?

Comment: apt usually doesn't just remove a package, unless it was automatically installed (in which case you could set it to manual), or if a new package replaces it. What's the exact situation you face? Is it a lib or a program?

Comment: I got issue with libc6 package on my home system (amd64+i386). Right now debian have libc6:i386=2.24-5 and  libc6:i386=2.24-6. During dist-upgrade apt removed my xorg-xserver-core, nvidia-driver and left me without desktop. I want to 'pin' them to prevent such things, but I want to allow upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: @KarstenKoop The information you gave is wrong. I ran into the same problem three days ago. Manually installed the package maitreya some years ago. Did apt-get dist-upgrade (Debian 11.7). Package maitreya was scheduled for removal, so I aborted the dist-upgrad and set the package to hold. `apt-mark showmanual` does list the package maitreya (as manually installed). Actually `apt-get dist-upgrade` does remove manually installed packages on dist-upgrade (as of october 2023). Apparently this happens when they're no more in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a solution using equiv:

create a control file looking like:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: my-dummy-essential
Depends: emacs, kdenlive, firefox, kde-plasma-desktop, task-kde-desktop, task-french-kde-desktop, mypaint, keepassxc, tmux, zsh, openssh-client
Prerm: my-prerm
Description: just a package that refuse to be unistalled
```

The Depends line should contain the list of the package you want to protect,

the prerm line refer to a script (named my-prerm here):

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
    
if [ "$1" != remove ]; then
    exit 0
fi
    
echo "are you sure about removing your essential package? (y/N)"
read i
if [ "x$i" = "xy" ]; then
   exit 0
fi
    
false
```

The idea is that this prerm script will failed (unless you accept the removal of the package), and that will prevent removal of the package, and of its depends.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a specific package to be upgraded you should put it on hold :

You can hold a package using:

```
sudo apt-mark hold package_name
```

or

```
sudo aptitude hold package_name
```

Or:

```
echo "package_name hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To remove the hold you should run:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

or

```
sudo aptitude unhold package_name
```

or

```
echo "package_name install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

**Blacklist the package:**

You can add your package under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` , edit your file then add the needed package under `Never-MarkAuto-Sections`

Comment: Unfortunately, hold forbids package upgrades. This is not what I want. I want to allow upgrade/downgrade of package, but forbid uninstallation.